# react toggle returns wrong state on initial state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I want to toggle my state `rememberMe` when the user checks the `rememberMe` checkbox.

The initial state is `false`; when I click I want it to turn to `true` so that I can set another condition, however this does not happen.

The prop `rememberMe` remains false on first click then changes to true on second click.

Does anyone know why this is?

code:

```
state = {
orderForm: {
  email: {
        elementType: "input-email",
        elementConfig: {
          type: "email",
          placeholder: "Your E-Mail"
        },
        value: this.props.email || "",
        validation: {
          required: true
        },
        valid: this.props.email ? true : false,
        touched: false
      },
},
 rememberMe: false

}
```

input

```
   return (
            <Input
              inputtype={formElement.config.elementType}
              key={formElement.id}
              elementType={formElement.config.elementType}
              elementConfig={formElement.config.elementConfig}
              value={formElement.config.value}
              invalid={!formElement.config.valid}
              shouldValidate={formElement.config.validation}
              touched={formElement.config.touched}
              changed={event => this.inputChangedHandler(event, formElement.id)}
              rememberMe={this.state.rememberMe}
              checkboxChanged={this.handleCheckboxChange}
            />
          );
```

function to change toggle:

````
  handleCheckboxChange = event => {
    this.setState((previousState) => {
      return {rememberMe: !previousState.rememberMe}
    });
    console.log(this.state.rememberMe);

    // setting local storage for email
    const email = this.state.orderForm.email.value;
    const rememberMe = this.state.rememberMe;
    localStorage.setItem("rememberMe", rememberMe);
    localStorage.setItem("email", rememberMe ? email : "");
  };```
````

Comment: try `const rememberMe = !this.state.rememberMe;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In react the state updates are asynchronous. So when doing `this.setState` react does not guarantee that it will update the state immediately. That's the reason `this.state.rememberMe` will not have new value inside handleClick function. Best way is to use current state to determine the value and use it.

So inside handleClick function you can do this:

````
  handleCheckboxChange = event => {
    const rememberMe = !this.state.rememberMe; // storing the required value in a variable
    this.setState((previousState) => {
      return {rememberMe: !previousState.rememberMe}
    });

    // setting local storage for email
    const email = this.state.orderForm.email.value;
    localStorage.setItem("rememberMe", rememberMe);
    localStorage.setItem("email", rememberMe ? email : "");
  };```
````

Please checkout out the following setState [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

Comment: So `const rememberMe = !this.state.rememberMe;` is creating a new current state and setting it to `true` to begin with in my `handleCheckboxChange` function, is that correct? Then I am using `this.setState`  to set the state of the  `rememberMe` prop based on the `previousState` .... can you clarify what the `previousState` is in this case? Is it the ``const rememberMe = !this.state.rememberMe;` ?

Comment: `const rememberMe = !this.state.rememberMe;` is just assigning the required value to the variable, so that it can be further used in the function. It is not creating a new state.

Also the `prevState` is a reference to the component state at the time the change is being applied. So it contains the current state value.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `setState` is asynchronous, so changes you make to state will not be applied until some time after `handleCheckboxChange` fires.  So `console.log(this.state.rememberMe)` won't echo your state updates, as it seems you are expecting.

Comment: OK, how will I know when the state has changed then? I did not know that changes I made to the were not updated straight away...you lean something new every day.

Comment: @AngelaInniss If you add a function to your component class named `componentDidUpdate`, React will call it every time there is a completed change to state or the component's props.  You can use it to take some action whenever state (or props) changes.  The full signature is `componentDidUpdate(previousProps, previousState)` You can compare the current state with the previous state passed in to determine exactly what changed when this function is called.

Comment: ok that makes sense. If I want to take some action based on a change in state I can use the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method OK. But what if I want the state to be updated immediately and not wait. Is there no way to immediately update state in React? I.e click a button call a method to change state then call another method that uses the updated state? This is something I am struggling with at the moment. I may ask another question on it soon

Comment: @AngelaInniss You're right; because of state's volatile nature, it would be a bad idea to rely on it as your data model.  A couple strategies that work here: make your data model a singleton object available to your entire application; then when you change a property on the data model, also change the same property on state, or (even better) take a look at Redux.